# Django url rewrites and passing a parameter from Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

As a bit of a followup question to my previous , I need to pass a parameter to a view. This parameter is not known until the JS executes.

In my URLConf:

```
url(r'^person/device/program/oneday/(?P<meter_id>\d+)/(?P<day_of_the_week>\w+)/$',
therm_control.Get_One_Day_Of_Current_Thermostat_Schedule.as_view(), 
name="one-day-url"),
```

I can pass it this URL and it works great! ( thanks to you guys).

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/personview/person/device/program/oneday/149778/Monday/
```

In My template I have this:

```
var one_day_url = "{% url personview:one-day-url meter_id=meter_id day_of_the_week='Monday' %}";
```

In my javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: one_day_url ,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        beforeSend: beforeSendCallback,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback,
        complete: completeCallback
    });
```

When this triggers it works fine except I dont necessarily want Monday all the time.

If I change the javascript to this:

```
var one_day_url = "{% url personview:one-day-url meter_id=meter_id %}";

and then

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: one_day_url + '/Monday/',
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        beforeSend: beforeSendCallback,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback,
        complete: completeCallback
    });
```

I get the Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering error. I assume because the URLconf still wants to rewrite to include the ?P\w+) .

I seems like if I change the URL conf that breaks the abailty to find the view , and if I do what I do above it gives me the NoREverseMatch error.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to use this kind of project which is meant to answer to this precise question...

notice: it may help hacker to map the website:
https://github.com/Dimitri-Gnidash/django-js-utils

When I don't use this project I put a default value in the url and replace it by correct value.

so use a complete reverse then:

```
url: one_day_url.replace('/Monday/','/Caturday/')
```

and even if you replace monday by monday it will works...

note: this ugly haks will fail if your default value is already sooner in the url so use it consequently.

Comment: After I posted the question I remembered replace and it does work. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution that works within the proper functioning of the framework. Thanks much!

Comment: You are welcome. The linked library may be a good answer for complex problems to avoid to repeat yourself and keep flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do something along the lines of

```
var one_day_url = "{% url personview:one-day-url meter_id=meter_id day_of_the_week='REPLACE_ME' %}";
// ...
url: one_day_url.replace('REPLACE_ME', 'Sunday')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass them in as part of the request data.  You can use the jQuery get function and pass them in as paramaters.

```
$.get("{%url personview%}", {'meter_id':"meter_id", "day_of_the_week":"monday" ...}, function(){do stuff when info is returned});
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
meter = request.GET['meter_id']
```

This will allow you to use it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question. I wanted to open a URL when someone clicked a button. For what it's worth, here is how I handled this situation.

Define the URL as an attribute:

```
{% for article in articles %}    
  <button data-article-url="{% url view_article article.id %}">
    Read Article #{{ article.id }}
  </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Using jQuery, read the attribute and carry on:

```
var article_url = $(this).attr("data-article-url");

$.ajax({
  url: article_url,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tokens in your url and pass it as a variable to your module:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/my-module.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    MyModule.init(
        "{% url personview:one-day-url meter_id='0000' day_of_the_week='{day}' %}"
    );
});
</script>
```

```
// js/my-module.js
var MyModule = {
    init: function(one_day_url) {
        var id = 1, day = 'Saturday';
        this._one_day_url = one_day_url;
        console.log(this.one_day_url(id, day));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: this.one_day_url(id, day),
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 30000,
            beforeSend: beforeSendCallback,
            success: successCallback,
            error: errorCallback,
            complete: completeCallback
        });
    },
    one_day_url: function(meter_id, day) {
        return this._one_day_url.replace('0000', meter_id).replace('{day}', day);
    }
};
```

Notice that token should match the regex type to resolve successfully (I can't use `{meter_id}` because it's defined with `\d+`).

I'm a little bit unsatisfied with this solution and I ended by writing my own application to handle javascript with django: [django.js](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django.js). With this application, I can do:

```
{% load js %}
{% django_js %}
{% js "js/my-module.js" %}
```

```
// js/my-module.js
var MyModule = {
    init: function() {
        var id = 1, day = 'Saturday';

        console.log(
            Django.url('personview:one-day-url', id, day),
            Django.url('personview:one-day-url', [id, day]),
            Django.url('personview:one-day-url', {
                meter_id: id,
                day_of_week: day
            })
        );

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: Django.url('personview:one-day-url', id, day),
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 30000,
            beforeSend: beforeSendCallback,
            success: successCallback,
            error: errorCallback,
            complete: completeCallback
        });
    }
};

$(function(){
    MyModule.init();
});
```